# K-medioids with Dynamic Time Warping in RapidMiner

Tags: cluster-analysis, rapidminer

How to perform K-medioids clustering with Dynamic Time Warping as a distance measure in RapidMiner?

The idea with Dynamic Time Warping is to perform it on time series of different length. How can I do that in RapidMiner? I get this error message

```
The data contains missing values which is not allowed for KMediods
```

How can I cluster time series of different length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could fill the missing values with zeroes. The operator `Replace Missing Values` does this. I don't know the details of your data nor how RapidMiner calculates DTW distances so I therefore can't tell if this approach would yield valid results.

Faced with this, I might use the R extension with the `dtw` and `cluster` packages to investigate how distances between different length time series could be used to make clusters. Once you have R working, you can call it from RapidMiner.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've done it with Replace Missing Values, but it is rather strange that it requires that two signals have same length, while DTW can work with signals of different length. Do you perhaps have any idea why is that?

Comment: I suppose DTW within RapidMiner was intended initially as a basic implementation and it does take time and money to write the code that perhaps they thought was not a priority. Some of the features the R `dtw` package exposes are very desirable so these could be good enhancements to be made to the RapidMiner implementation. Of course, it is relatively easy just to call the R `dtw` package directly.